# Move navigation position outside of timeline

Tags: primefaces, timeline, primefaces-extensions

I am using prime faces 6.0 timeline tag for displaying data. I need the navigation and zoom buttons to displayed outside of the timeline graph. I have marked the navigation options in the attached image.

[Timeline Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgdFQ.png)

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and [mcve] and improve your question

Comment: is this feasible??

Comment: No idea... Tried css?

Comment: @Kukeltje nope Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Sorry, no, StackOverflow (at least from my point of view) is not a private learning service. If you have no idea on how to experiment with applying css to html pages, take some tutorial on that on e.g. http://www.htmldog.com/

Comment: @Kukeltje i tried with CSS but whenever timeline is updating its back to its original position

Comment: Then write better CSS...

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you genius

Comment: What do you expect? I'm not clairvoyant so I'm totally unable to see what you tried. My FIRST comment was about that. You did not comply with that yet keep asking things, making statements that are completely useless. Sorry, but this way it just looks if you want others to do the full work for you and that is not how stackoverflow works. (Oh, btw, like I said, I'm not clairvoyant, but a genius I indeed am, good you noticed)